# AQGridView - Orientation change in ExpanderDemo

Tags: iphone, ios, gridview, uiviewcontroller, aqgridview

I just started checking **AQGridView** and new to iOS too in the source example **ExpanderDemo** the orientation is working fine for the first View but as i click any cell and next upcomming AQGridView does not effect View on GridView.

```
ExpandingGridViewController *controller = [[ExpandingGridViewController alloc] init];
    controller.gridView.frame = self.gridView.frame;
    [self.gridView setHidden:YES];
    [self.view.superview addSubview: controller.gridView];
    [controller expandCellsFromRect: expandFromRect ofView: cell];
    [controller viewDidAppear: NO];
```

On the other hand if i present the view controller to second it works fine with the orientation but losses the Animation for Expansion; which i don't want to loose. What should i do?

```
ExpandingGridViewController *controller = [[ExpandingGridViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

The last time I use AQGridView I got a lot of troubles, I suggest You should give a try to UICollectionView. Cheers!